# Is possible to click the js tree node to echo the data?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

May I know is possible to click the js tree node to echo the data? My question is same like this question [Click the each node in the js tree to show the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62518536/click-the-each-node-in-the-js-tree-to-show-the-value)

Below is show the data method coding:

```html
<h5>No. Pindaan [siri_pindaan input from user] Tarikh Berkuatkuasa [effective_date input from user]</h5>

$folders_arr[] = array(
 "id" => $row['id'],
"parent" => $parentid,
 "text" => $row['name'] . ' ' ."<span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'>".$refer_to_code .$row['filing_code_refer']."</span>" .' '. "<span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'>".$link_to_code .$row['filing_code_link']."</span>" .' '. "<span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'>".$row['description_update']."</span>".' '. "<span id='open'>".$siri_pindaan_edit."</span>",
"category" => $row['category'],
"filing_code_refer" => $row['filing_code_refer'],
"siri_pindaan" => $row['siri_pindaan'],
"effective_date" = $row['effective_date'];
"data" => array("status" => $row['status'],"add_underline"=>$row['add_underline']) ,
"state" => array("selected" => $selected,"opened"=>$opened) 
);
```

I need to show **$row['siri_pindaan']** and **$row['effective_date']** values in the **h5**. My expected result like below the picture if I've click the 500 PENGURUSAN SUMBER MALAYSIA tree node, the value 966 and 2020-06-26 will show on the **h5** top.

[image: images]

Comment: can you add the jsfiddle, like your prev question. that will help to debug and provide you the solution

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5cng28d9/
Thank you take time to help me.

Comment: @DeepakSharma May I know this question is possible get the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so first we will bind `changed.jstree` event, and will grab the node text value.

```
.on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
     let nodeText = data.instance.get_node(data.selected[0]).text;    
})
```

Im assuming you will have `pindaan` and `tarikh` in the same format. something like below -

`(NO.PINDAAN [NUMBER_HERE] TARIKH BERKUATKUASA [DATE_HERE] )`

so we will use regex to fetch your variable from the template.

```
var regRet = nodeText.match(/(NO.PINDAAN (.*) TARIKH BERKUATKUASA (.*) )/i);
if(regRet && regRet.length === 4) {
   renderData(regRet[2], regRet[3]);
} else {
   renderData('  ', '  ');
}
```

and then call another function `renderData`, which actual populate values in heading.

```
  function renderData(pindaan, tarikh) {
    $('#pindaan').html(pindaan);
    $('#tarikh').html(tarikh);
  }
```

also set the value to empty if node doesn't have `pindaan` and `tarikh` value

```html
    <html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>

    <div class="box">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
    <header>
    <h5>No. Pindaan [<span id="pindaan"> </span>] Tarikh Berkuatkuasa [<span id="tarikh"> </span>] </h5>
    </header>
    <div id="div-4" class="body">
    <div class="x_content">
    <!-- Initialize jsTree -->
    <div id="folder_jstree" title=""></div>
    <!-- Store folder list in JSON format -->
    <textarea style="" id='txt_folderjsondata'>[{"id":"658","parent":"#","text":"100 PENTADBIRAN <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'>FAIL BARU<\/span> <span id='open'><\/span>","category":"JTM","filing_code_refer":"","data":{"status":"1","add_underline":"0"},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"659","parent":"#","text":"200 PENGURUSAN TANAH & BANGUNAN <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'><\/span> <span id='open'>(NO.PINDAAN 666 TARIKH BERKUATKUASA 2020-06-25 )<\/span>","category":"JTM","filing_code_refer":"","data":{"status":"1","add_underline":"0"},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"660","parent":"#","text":"300 PENGURUSAN ASET <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'><\/span> <span id='open'>(NO.PINDAAN 777 TARIKH BERKUATKUASA 2020-06-19 )<\/span>","category":"JTM","filing_code_refer":"","data":{"status":"1","add_underline":"0"},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"661","parent":"#","text":"400 PENGURUSAN KEWANGAN <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'><\/span> <span id='open'>(NO.PINDAAN 966 TARIKH BERKUATKUASA 2020-06-26 )<\/span>","category":"JKP","filing_code_refer":"","data":{"status":"1","add_underline":"0"},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"662","parent":"#","text":"500 PENGURUSAN SUMBER MANUSIA <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'><\/span> <span id='open'>(NO.PINDAAN 966 TARIKH BERKUATKUASA 2020-06-26 )<\/span>","category":"JKP","filing_code_refer":"","data":{"status":"1","add_underline":"0"},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"663","parent":"658","text":"100-1 PERUNDANGAN <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'><\/span> <span id='open'>(NO.PINDAAN 966 TARIKH BERKUATKUASA 2020-06-26 )<\/span>","category":"JTM","filing_code_refer":"","data":{"status":"1","add_underline":"0"},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"664","parent":"658","text":"100-2 PERHUBUNGAN AWAM <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'><\/span> <span id='open'>(NO.PINDAAN 966 TARIKH BERKUATKUASA 2020-06-26 )<\/span>","category":"JKP","filing_code_refer":"","data":{"status":"1","add_underline":"0"},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"665","parent":"663","text":"100-1-1 PENGGUBALAN-PENYEDIAAN-PINDAAN UNDANG-UNDANG-PERATURAN <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'><\/span> <span id='open'>(NO.PINDAAN 966 TARIKH BERKUATKUASA 2020-06-26 )<\/span>","category":"JTM","filing_code_refer":"","data":{"status":"1","add_underline":"0"},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"666","parent":"663","text":"100-1-2 KHIDMAT NASIHAT <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'><\/span> <span id='open'>(NO.PINDAAN 966 TARIKH BERKUATKUASA 2020-06-26 )<\/span>","category":"JTM","filing_code_refer":"","data":{"status":"1","add_underline":"0"},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"667","parent":"665","text":"100-1-1-1 UNDANG-UNDANG KECIL KERJA DI JALAN 1996 <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'><\/span> <span id='open'>(NO.PINDAAN 966 TARIKH BERKUATKUASA 2020-06-26 )<\/span>","category":"JTM","filing_code_refer":"","data":{"status":"1","add_underline":"0"},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"668","parent":"665","text":"100-1-1-2 UNDANG-UNDANG KECIL PERUNTUKAN MENGENAI LESEN BERSESAMA (MAJLIS PERBANDARAN) <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'><\/span> <span id='open'>(NO.PINDAAN 966 TARIKH BERKUATKUASA 2020-06-26 )<\/span>","category":"JTM","filing_code_refer":"","data":{"status":"1","add_underline":"0"},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"670","parent":"666","text":"100-1-2-1 JABATAN PENGUATKUASAAN <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'><\/span> <span id='open'>(NO.PINDAAN 966 TARIKH BERKUATKUASA 2020-06-26 )<\/span>","category":"JTM","filing_code_refer":"","data":{"status":"1","add_underline":"0"},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"671","parent":"666","text":"100-1-2-2 JABATAN BANGUNAN <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'><\/span> <span id='open'>(NO.PINDAAN 966 TARIKH BERKUATKUASA 2020-06-26 )<\/span>","category":"JTM","filing_code_refer":"","data":{"status":"1","add_underline":"0"},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"672","parent":"664","text":"100-2-1 PUBLISITI, PROMOSI DAN PROTOKOL <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'><\/span> <span id='open'>(NO.PINDAAN 966 TARIKH BERKUATKUASA 2020-06-26 )<\/span>","category":"JKP","filing_code_refer":"","data":{"status":"1","add_underline":"0"},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"673","parent":"672","text":"100-2-1-1 PUBLISITI DAN KENYATAAN MEDIA <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'>Berhubung Kod:999<\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'><\/span> <span id='open'>(NO.PINDAAN 966 TARIKH BERKUATKUASA 2020-06-26 )<\/span>","category":"JKP","filing_code_refer":"","data":{"status":"1","add_underline":"0"},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"674","parent":"665","text":"100-1-1-3 UNDANG-UNDANG KECIL MENGKOMPAUN KESALAHAN-KESALAHAN (MAJLIS PERBANDARAN KLANG) <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'>Rujuk Kod:TEST<\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'><\/span> <span id='open'>(NO.PINDAAN 966 TARIKH BERKUATKUASA 2020-06-26 )<\/span>","category":"JTM (BERHUBUNG KOD 100-1\/1\/2)","filing_code_refer":"TEST","data":{"status":"1","add_underline":"0"},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}},{"id":"755","parent":"#","text":"123 TEST <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'>Rujuk Kod:123<\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'><\/span> <span id='open'>(NO.PINDAAN 123 TARIKH BERKUATKUASA 2020-06-16 )<\/span>","category":"jtm","filing_code_refer":"123","data":{"status":"1","add_underline":"0"},"state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}}]</textarea>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-offset-5" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Print</button>
                </div>
                       
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </html>
    <script style="text/javascript">
     let obj = {
        pindaan:'',
        tarikh:''
     }
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var folder_jsondata = JSON.parse($('#txt_folderjsondata').val());

        $('#folder_jstree')
        .on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
           let nodeText = data.instance.get_node(data.selected[0]).text;
    var regRet = nodeText.match(/(NO.PINDAAN (.*) TARIKH BERKUATKUasa (.*) )/i);
    if(regRet && regRet.length === 4) {
        renderData(regRet[2], regRet[3]);
    } else {
      renderData('  ', '  ');
    }    
  })
        .jstree({
          'core': {
            'data': folder_jsondata,
            'multiple': false
          },
          'plugins': ['sort'],
          'sort': function(a, b) {
            return this.get_text(a).localeCompare(this.get_text(b), 'en', {
              numeric: true
            });
          }
        });

        var getColor = function(i) {
          if (i >= 100 && i <= 199) {
            return "blue";
          } else if (i >= 200 && i <= 299) {
            return "red";
          } else if (i >= 300 && i <= 399) {
            return "yellow";
          } else if (i >= 400 && i <= 499) {
            return "purple";
          } else if (i >= 500 && i <= 599) {
            return "green";
          } else {
            return "#000";
          }
        };
        
        
        
        var colorNodes = function(nodelist) {
            var getStrike = function(status) {
          if (status === "0") {
            return "line-through";
          }  else {
            return "";
          }
        };
        
            var getUnderline = function(add_underline) {
          if (add_underline === "1") {
            return " underline;text-underline-position: under;";
          }  else {
            return "";
          }
        };
          var tree = $('#folder_jstree').jstree(true);
          nodelist.forEach(function(n) {
            tree.get_node(n.id).a_attr.style = "color:" + getColor(parseInt(n.text.substr(0, 3), 10))+ ";"+"text-decoration:" + getStrike(n.data.status) + getUnderline(n.data.add_underline);
            tree.redraw_node(n.id); //Redraw tree
            colorNodes(n.children); //Update leaf nodes
          });
        };

        $('#folder_jstree').bind('load_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
          var tree = $('#folder_jstree').jstree(true);
          colorNodes(tree.get_json());
        });
        
        
        $('#folder_jstree').bind('hover_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
          $("#" + data.node.id).attr("title", data.node.original.category);
        });

      });
      
      
      function renderData(pindaan, tarikh) {
        $('#pindaan').html(pindaan);
        $('#tarikh').html(tarikh);
      }
      
    </script>
```

You can also find the working fiddle here.

https://jsfiddle.net/ewk0ay2r/

Comment: Can you help me check my code?https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u_MTbqCvfjn_HiW6XN2cBcvrcmVn1Fqq/view?usp=sharing

Because my side cannot. Your side can.

Comment: Sorry. I find the problem. Your solution is corrected. Thanks your helping. Save my day.

Comment: Hi @Deepak Sharma. I have a quesiton similar the js coding. If you have time can help me to check it. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62669094/show-color-in-js-nodes

Comment: Hi, friend. I have new question similar this question stackoverflow.com/questions/62751925/… If you have free, can help me to see. Thanks.