# How to remove selected underline and line-through in the js tree?

Tags: javascript, css, jstree

I have a problem to remove the line-through in the js tree. For example now my tree nodes is 199 test Rujuk Kod:100-1-1. I have added the line-through in the **199 test Rujuk Kod:100-1-1**. But I just want add in the **199 test**, Rujuk Kod:100-1-1 don't want add line-through. Hope someone can help me solve this problem. Thanks.

Below is my coding:

```html
<?php 

$folderData = mysqli_query($mysql_con,"SELECT * FROM filing_code_management");
$folders_arr = array();
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($folderData)){
 $parentid = $row['parentid'];
$siri_pindaan = $row['siri_pindaan'];
$effective_date = $row['effective_date'];
 $filing_code_refer = $row['filing_code_refer'];
$filing_code_link = $row['filing_code_link'];
        if ($filing_code_refer != NULL) {
        $refer_to_code = "Rujuk Kod:";
        }
        if ($filing_code_refer == NULL) {
        $refer_to_code = " ";
        }
        if ($filing_code_link != NULL) {
        $link_to_code = "Berhubung Kod:";
        }
        if ($filing_code_link == NULL) {
        $link_to_code = " ";
        }

    
      if($parentid == '0') $parentid = "#";

      $selected = false;$opened = false;
      if($row['id'] == 2){
         $selected = true;$opened = true;
      }
      $folders_arr[] = array(
    
         "id" => $row['id'],
         "parent" => $parentid,
         "text" => $row['name'] . ' ' ."<span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'>".$refer_to_code .$row['filing_code_refer']."</span>" .' '. "<span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'>".$link_to_code .$row['filing_code_link']."</span>" .' '. "<span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'>".$row['description_update']."</span>",
         "category" => $row['category'],
         "filing_code_refer" => $row['filing_code_refer'],
         // "status" => $row['status'], // status 0 is inactive, status 1 is active
         "data" => array("status" => $row['status'],"add_underline"=>$row['add_underline']) ,
         "state" => array("selected" => $selected,"opened"=>$opened) 
     
      );
   }

   ?> 

<script>
 var colorNodes = function(nodelist) {
        var getStrike = function(status) {
      if (status === "0") {
        return "line-through";
      }  else {
        return "";
      }
    };
    
        var getUnderline = function(add_underline) {
      if (add_underline === "1") {
        return " underline;text-underline-position: under;";
      }  else {
        return "";
      }
    };
      var tree = $('#folder_jstree').jstree(true);
      nodelist.forEach(function(n) {
        tree.get_node(n.id).a_attr.style = "color:" + getColor(parseInt(n.text.substr(0, 3), 10))+ ";"+"text-decoration:" + getStrike(n.data.status) + getUnderline(n.data.add_underline);
        tree.redraw_node(n.id); //Redraw tree
        colorNodes(n.children); //Update leaf nodes
      });
    };
</script>
```

This is my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mLr5w2pd/1/

My expected result is like below the picture:

[image]

**Updated**
Below is show the content in the js tree.

```html
<!-- Initialize jsTree -->
            <div id="folder_jstree" title=""></div>
            <!-- Store folder list in JSON format -->
            <textarea style="" id='txt_folderjsondata'><?= json_encode($folders_arr) ?></textarea>
```

**Updated 2**

[image: images2]

Comment: Change the status to "1" instead of "0". As you can see in `getStrike()`.

Comment: @Lain status cannot change to 0 because need to check this node is actived or inactive

Comment: if inactive 0 the line-through will show. But now I just want Rujuk Kod:100-1-1 no need put the line-through

Comment: Ah well, that is not how it works by default. Give those `span` a class and cancel it on the class.

Comment: Thanks @Lain give me suggestion. Can you show me in the below which code need to edit? Then if correct I can give you mark.

Comment: Or you can using my jsfiddle to show me. Thanks.

Comment: @SoonWinner content in text area, that you generate? can you customized that not to generate empty span? if yes, I can give you the solution? we can tweak CSS a little bit

Comment: @DeepakSharma Yes. I have updated which to show my js tree content

Comment: content in text area is generated from the database

Comment: @DeepakSharma  yes, you can give me the solution

Comment: I am not sure how to edit in the javascript

Comment: with css you can overwrite the `text-decoration` prop, no need to modify the JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add below css to make the `span` inside the `jstree-anchor` as `inline-block`, then it will not have 'line-through'

```
.jstree-anchor span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mL407ya1/

and if you notice you have `line-through` in last, that is because of space in below code line #2 (`text`)-

```
{
 "id":"753","parent":"#",
 "text":"199 test <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'>Rujuk Kod:190-1-1<\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span> <span id='open' style='font-size:9px;'> <\/span>",
 "category":"jtm",
  "filing_code_refer":"190-1-1",
  "data":{"status":"0","add_underline":"0"},
  "state":{"selected":false,"opened":false}
}
```

if you can remove the space between `<span>` and `</span>` it will work as expected.

**UPDATE**

if you can't remove the spaces from source, in code you can remove the space using regex.  while you are parsing string to json array, remove the extra space before parsing. try below

```
let txtVal = $('#txt_folderjsondata').val();
txtVal = txtVal.replace(/> </g, '><');
var folder_jsondata = JSON.parse(txtVal);
```

Try the below fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/mL407ya1/1/
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The last line-through can remove?

Comment: we can remove the extra spaces using regex. let me update the answer

Comment: Thanks @Deepak. You are absolutely clever.

Comment: I think you are expected in javascript. If you have time can you help me see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62524992/is-possible-to-click-the-js-tree-node-to-echo-the-data

Comment: Hi @Deepak Sharma. I have a quesiton similar the js coding. If you have time can help me to check it. Thanks. stackoverflow.com/questions/62669094/show-color-in-js-nodes

Comment: Hi, friend. I have new question similar this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62751925/color-show-not-properly-in-the-js-tree#  If you have free, can help me to see. Thanks.